# What to call idiomatic Swift code, equivalent of pythonic?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In Python there is a phrase used to describe code that written leveraging the idioms of Python (for-in loops vs for loops, etc). We say such code is *Pythonic*.

> Is there a similar term for Apple's new Swift language? *Swiftonic*? *Swiftic*?

Are we just stuck with *idiomatic swift code* (a description rather than term)?

Just to give you an idea of what I'm talking about here is an example. Both code blocks find the index of a letter in a string:

**Non-swiftic(?) code [bad]**:

```
// extension method on the String class
func findIndexOf(char : String) -> Int? {

    for var i = 0; i < countElements(self); ++i {
        var ch = String(Array(self)[i])
        if String(ch) == char {
            return i
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

**Swiftic(?) code [good]**:

```
// extension method on the String class
func findIndexOf(char : String) -> Int? {

    for (index, ch) in enumerate(self) {
        if String(ch) == char {
            return index
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: `Non-swiftonic(?) code [bad]:` Why its bad or why other is good? Its only difference of code style. Both have iteration index. From my view Swift is a new language and I think its early to talk about concepts :)

Comment: @rintaro I like Swiftic!

Comment: @MaximShoustin I think there are definitely ways of *fighting* a language vs *embracing* its key features. The first style definitely seems to be against the grain IMO. :)

Comment: Swift is already an adjective so... **swift Swift**?

Comment: Maybe just... **swifty**?

Comment: I think "Swift" works quite nicely itself. "That code is not very Swift."

Comment: I do not think this question is 'opinion based' (being put on hold for that...). I do not feel that the concept of a language having idioms is an opinion. Languages *have* idioms. My question is simply what term does this new community want to adopt to speak about *their* opinions on others code. But I am not expressing an opinion in this question at all AFAIK.

Comment: I like "Swiftian", personally. It's already in use to describe work that's in the style of Jonathan Swift, but I think we can probably live with that ambiguity :D. But while you're not expressing an opinion in the question, the problem is that *answers* to it will be opinion-based, so I can see why it got closed.